# 'DATEDIFE' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i have problem in below code  any body can help me?
it's shows       (DATEDIFE' is not a recognized built-in function name.) Error

```
        com.CommandText = "select DATEDIFE(year,'2008-06-05','2010-06-05') AS XXX";

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
```

Best Regards
Alireza

Comment: [**DATEDIFF**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) not `DATEDIFE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, Datedife -> Datediff. Try:

```
select Datediff(year,'2008-06-05','2010-06-05') AS XXX
```

Answer (score 1):

Its `DATEDIFF`

```
 com.CommandText = "select DATEDIFF(year,'2008-06-05','2010-06-05') AS XXX";

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `DATEDIFF`

```
com.CommandText = "select DATEDIFF(year,'2008-06-05','2010-06-05') AS XXX";
```

Answer (score 0):

use DATEDIFF(instead of DATEDIFE its a wrong keyword)

There is a spelling mistake in your query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR,'2008-06-05','2010-06-05') AS XXX
```